# Angular: function in service vs components?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, service, components

We've got an `Angular` app consisting of excel-like grids. There are at least 20 components, each with a unique grid.

Each component has a `save()` function which cycles through any added, edited or deleted items and saves them accordingly. `save()` is a large function and exists on each component's .ts file, since there are differences between each `save()`.

I wanted to refactor `save()`, so I started with one of the components. Then I realized that it may have been easier if I centralized the function within a service and just had one `save()` for the whole app, rather than 20 (one on each component). However, I also see cons to this. **I'm hoping other Angular devs can give me some insight into reasons to put a function into a service, rather than leaving it in each component.**

**PROS** 
- might make development easier - aka if refactor is needed, only need to refactor in one place. However, may not be the case:

**CONS** 
- might make development/maintenance *more* difficult, or not any easier. Because, the differences between `save()` on each component are sometimes rather significant, and: 
- likely will decrease performance of `save()`, since differences will require additional `switch case` statements to determine which component is calling `save()`. It may not be a noticeable performance hit, but there will be a hit. 
- this will take weeks to consolidate and test - everything's working right now and would be a shame to break something

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

An approach to creating a service for the *save* functionality would be to have a `BaseSave` class which would have `protected` methods (same as *private* but available to classes that extend it) that have all of the functionality that is common to the different save scenarios. The `BaseSave` would not itself be provided as a service

For each of the different components (where save would differ), you would create an injectable service that *extends BaseSave*. These would use the *protected* methods, but would also provide their own unique implementations of the `public save()` function

Unit tests could be written for the `BaseSave` class and also for each of the extended implementations